# focus com texto selecionado

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho um input on quero que ele tenha focus e que o texto já esteja selecionado.

O focus estou fazendo assim:

```
$(".autofocus").trigger('focus');
```

O problema e que o texto não fica selecionado. Alguém sabe como fazer isso?

Answer (score 4):

Coloque esse código antes do código da trigger:

```
$(".autofocus").on("focus", function () {
   $(this).select();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

O `.on()` é dispensável atualmente, bastaria ([conforme documentação](https://api.jquery.com/focus/)) antes da `.trigger()` o seguinte código:

```
$(".autofocus").focus(function () {
    $(this).select();
});
```

Você pode ainda realizar diretamente no elemento:

```
<input class="autofocus" type="text" onfocus="this.select();" onmouseup="return false;" />
```

Comment: Costumo utilizar o on por padrão pois ele funciona inclusive quando o input é colocado dinamicamente na página. Aliás utilizo ate $(document).on("focus", ".autofocus", function(){}); que abrange mais casos ainda.